# Algorithm for auto convolution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computational-complexity, convolution, recursive-algorithms

I have a question, since we have a divide and conquer algorithm for calculate normal convolution sequence in n^log(3) [n power log 3 base 2] , i thought maybe symmetric feature in auto-convolution can help for better complexity. If you know better algorithm or not, please tell me that.

By symmetric i mean in a*b always a=b.

Thanks, 
Omid yaghoubi

Comment: I don't think that any asymptotic improvement is possible. Even if $a=b$, you still have to evaluate $3$ terms and each requires at least one product.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks :)